# sObject type 'Pricebook2__c' is not supported

Tags: rest-api, integration, data, wsdl

I'm working with integration with Salesforce, and when we're going to send data to Salesforce, this error occurs:

> INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'Pricebook2__c' is not supported. 
>   If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name.
>
> Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

The employee that take care of that area said that he does not edit the field name/API to remove some '__c', he can't edit this anywhere outside SF.

The Pricebook2 is a standard field, I only saw this kind of error searching around the internet, in custom objects/fields that couldn`t be deployed yet or some permition is missing etc. But we have the System Admin profile and it seems ok in the permission setup, so, I don't know where to start right now, anyone can give a little hand with this issue please?

Comment: You can find a list of all standard object and field names in the [API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to tell what data you're even working with, but the standard object name is simply [`Pricebook2`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_pricebook2.htm) (*no underscores*).

If you are trying to insert a record looking up to this object (*such as [`PricebookEntry`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_pricebookentry.htm)*), the name of the lookup field is `Pricebook2Id`.